# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_altitude'

Tags: python, python-3.x

This section of my pysolarrobot7.py code is throwing an AttributeError

```
def tomorrow_heading():
    increment_min = 1
    incrementeddatetime = 0
    tomorrow_corrected = 90
    if pysolar.get_altitude(maplat, maplon, datetime.datetime.utcnow()) < 0:
        while pysolar.get_altitude(maplat, maplon, (datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=incrementeddatetime))) < 0:
          incrementeddatetime = incrementeddatetime + increment_min
        sunrise_time=(datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=incrementeddatetime))
        tomorrow_heading = pysolar.GetAzimuth(maplat, maplon, sunrise_time)
        if tomorrow_heading < 0:
            if (tomorrow_heading >= -180):
                tomorrow_corrected = ((tomorrow_heading * -1) + 180)
            if (tomorrow_heading < -180):
                tomorrow_corrected = ((tomorrow_heading * -1) - 180)
        if tomorrow_heading >= 0:
```

The following is the error code

```
root@Primerpi:/tools# python3 solarrobot7-core.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solarrobot7-core.py", line 237, in <module>
    tomorrow_static = tomorrow_heading()
  File "solarrobot7-core.py", line 176, in tomorrow_heading
    if pysolar.get_altitude(maplat, maplon, datetime.datetime.utcnow()) < 0:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_altitude'
```

I've been googling for a while now and can't seem to find the answer.  The original code from solarrobot7.py used `GetAltitude` and `Pysolar` (PascalCase) and I changed it to `get_altitude` and `pysolar` (snake_case).

Comment: It seems to be saying that **pysolar** doesn't have a function in it's definition called **get_altitude**. Looking at a few other code examples on the net, I have to ask how you're importing pysolar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pysolar don't have an "get_altitude" method:
You want the sub-module "solar" :)

```
from pysolar import solar
solar.get_altitude #this will work :)
```

Comment: Thanks, guys.  i'll try to write the suggested lines into the code - before the first call - somewhere and experiment until i get it right.

Comment: Wow.  Thanks guys.  That seems to have done it.  Of course i get another, new error, but i'm going to look in "solar" to see if GetAzimuth has changed syntax, too.  Really appreciate - i'm no programmer.